# Determine the point(s), (if any), at which the graph of the function has a horizontal tangent.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the point(s), (if any), at which the graph of the function has a horizontal tangent. $y(x)= x^4-500x+2$

So I know the first thing to do is find the derivative which is:

$y'(x) = 4x^3-500$

I'm stuck here. Is there a formula to find $x$ values or do I divide by 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the graph to have a horizontal tangent at a particular value of $x$, $f'(x)$ must be zero for that $x$.

Comment: 4x^3-500=0. Then do I divide by 4?

Comment: Yes, that's probably a sensible next step. Remember, you are eventually trying to isolate $x$.

Comment: Okay. That's what I was thinking but wasn't sure.

Comment: Do you know what to do after the division?

Comment: After division I'm left with x^3-125=0. Then move 125 to other side. So I have x^3=125.

Comment: Yes. So... What's the last step to find $x$?

Comment: Okay so I don't know how to isolate x. I have x^3=125. Is it something like x=3√125

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right: you take the cube root of both sides. And, in fact, $\sqrt[3]{125}$ is...?

Comment: Okay so is it 5?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I had done but wasn't sure I was doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

A horizontal line has an equation of the form $y=b$. Its slope is zero, so you're looking for values of $x$ such that $f'(x)$ is zero. Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: Maybe. I'm going to divide 4x^3-500=0 by 4

Comment: @CSES That's a correct first step, then you would have: $x^3=125$ so you're looking for a number whose cube is $125$, can you find it?

Comment: 5. So is the answer √5?

Comment: @CSES That's correct $x^3=125\Rightarrow x=5$.

Comment: So does this graph have only one point?

Comment: @CSES I'll start responding here so that you don't have two conversations happening at once. Yes, there is only one point at which the function has a horizontal tangent (you know this because $4x^3-500=0$ has only one solution), and the $x$ position of that point$-$as you have figured out$-$is 5. You are very close to the answer. But what about the point's $y$ position?

Comment: (5,0)? or do I plug 5 for x and solve for y?

Comment: The latter. Do you understand why that is?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: @CSES The question is (presumably) asking for points actually _on_ the curve $y(x)=x^4-500x+2$. Every point on this curve is of the form $\left(x,y(x)\right)$; in fact, the curve is _defined_ as the set of points satisfying this form. So if you are looking for the point on the curve at $x=5$, you know that its "height", or $y$-value, is given by $y(5)=5^4-500(5)+2=-1823$.

Comment: @DivergentQueries Yes. It makes sense now. Thanks for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: I was happy to help!